# Adding number to Array without loop

Tags: matlab

Can you help me. I want to add these 3 values into Array (test) but without loops and without manual declaration of row and column. Is it possible?

```
clear all
clc

test = zeros(3,1);

first = 11;
first = 15;
first = 18;
```

I want to have in Array:

```
11
15
18
```

Comment: Do you want to end up with `[11;15;18]`?

Comment: @BillBokeey Yes. And maybe I will have more values for the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple instance array manipulation in MATLAB, and can be done for example using [`vertcat`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/vertcat.html):

```
test = vertcat(test, first, second, third)
```

Or same thing with different syntax:

```
test = [test; first; second; third]
```

Or if you want to actually end up with `[11; 15; 18`], do

```
test = vertcat(first, second, third)
```

or

```
test = [first; second; third]
```

Comment: You did not see my edit. What is if name of value is same and values different?

Comment: @Adriaan Could you help me...I want to add every new value of "first" in new row

Comment: @richi12 that's plain impossible, as the variables `first` will simply overwrite one another. As you have written it there, only `first = 18;` will survive.

Comment: @Adriaan I want to go on next row of Array. Is it possible?

Comment: @richi12 what next row? You don't make any sense here. Have you even read my previous comment? You can't define your variables that way and expect all 3 instances of `first` to exist and be callable.

Comment: You can write `first=12; first=[first;15];first=[first;18];`. That way each new entry comes to a new row in the array. Otherwise, as Adriaan told you, the value of `first` simply gets overwritten.